# react duplicate key mechanism

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to understand the result of this codes. I think it's related to React "keys."

```js
const {useState} = React;

/*export default*/ function App() {
  const [alphabets, setAlpabets] = useState([
    { key: "b", name: "b2" },
    { key: "b", name: "b" },
    { key: "a", name: "a1" },
    { key: "a", name: "a2" }
  ]);
  const handleChange = () => {
    setAlpabets([{ key: "a", name: "a3" }]);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {alphabets.map(({ key, name }) => (
        <p key={key}>{name}</p>
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleChange}>change</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

This code renders `b2`, `b`, `a1`, and `a2` initially, then when I trigger the `change` button the result is `b2`, `a1`, and `a3`.

I expected the result to be `a3` because after triggering the button, `alpabets` only has key "a". Why does it have the others?

Comment: **Keys must be unique,** but your keys are not unique. From [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html): *"Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed."* So if the keys aren't unique, React doesn't know what to remove. Notice that you get a nice error about this from the development versions of the libraries I used when converting your code block to a Stack Snippet. I suggest using the dev version of the libs during development, and making sure to look at and pay attention to errors in the devtools console.

Comment: thx for your comment @T.J.Crowder 
I know the key should be unique but what I wanna know why the result is this..

Comment: @SungwonWI - I told you why: React doesn't know which DOM elements to remove and which to keep. By reusing the key `a`, you've confused it, and it's kept all the elements using that key. (Also, just so you know since I don't think you're a native English speaker, "wanna" is **extremely** informal and not appropriate to even vaguely-professional situations, like posts and comments here on Stack Overflow. It's "want to" other than casually with friends.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you so much for your answer and advice! you make my day:)

Answer (score 0):

That error is normal, when you are using map to loop through a list of item in an array and use `key` to help react in magment of reference to each item inside of the loop the `key` props must be unique for each item in the `map` loop. In your case there are two item with the same key

```
{ key: "b", name: "b2" }
{ key: "b", name: "b" }
```

And

```
{ key: "a", name: "a1" }
{ key: "a", name: "a2" }
```

Their have the same value for the `key` property

To avoid to use `key` attribute of each object in the array you can use the index of that item like this

```
 return (
    <div className="App">
        {alphabets.map(({ key, name }, index) => (
            <p key={index}>{name}</p>
        ))}
        <button onClick={handleChange}>change</button>
    </div>
  );
```

You can read nore about [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0):

React keys should be unique, keys help react to track the changes happened to the item.

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

See more of [List and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html)